# Try to use react-native-fs in create-react-native-app project (expo)

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-native-fs

I'm trying to use react-native-fs in my app to upload files etc.
I followed the installation like the documentation, make the import and i'd put this code for the test :

```
componentDidMount(){
    const path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.txt';
    console.log(path);
    // write the file
    RNFS.writeFile(path, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'utf8')
        .then((success) => {
            console.log('FILE WRITTEN!');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err.message);
    });
}
```

And it's directly render me this error :

[image]
ps: I created my project via create-react-native-app

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need link react-native fs in your project .
run this in terminal react-native link react-native-fs